# How do I manually import these modules into Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been trying for a frustrating two hours, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to import these 3 folders for my project.

https://github.com/tronprotocol/trident/tree/main/trident-java

I need the folders `abi`, `core`, and `utils` in my project. I've tried everything I could think of.

Copying them into the `libs` folder and referencing them in my app's `build.gradle`. Importing as a module and library from `Project Structure`, and a bunch of other things.

I've watched a bunch of youtube tutorials where people insert it as a `.jar`, but these folders aren't jars and I can't find any examples where the user imports them as folders.

Could someone please help me figure out how to use those 3 folders in my project?

**Edit:**

The example they give on their github is to do this:

```
dependencies {
    // protobuf & grpc
    implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.11.0'

    implementation fileTree(dir:'../core')
    implementation fileTree(dir:'../utils')
    implementation fileTree(dir:'../abi')

    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.0-jre'
}
```

I've cloned the repository and copied those three folders into my project's
`TestProject/app/libs` folder.

I've changed the `build.gradle` file inside my app to

```
dependencies {
    //other dependencies

    implementation fileTree(dir:'libs/core')
    implementation fileTree(dir:'libs/utils')
    implementation fileTree(dir:'libs/abi')
}
```

There's no gradle syncing error, but I cannot get any methods of those libraries inside my `MainActivity`

Comment: Libs folder? Just put these three folders in same directory as app folder.

Comment: @blackapps Just tried, I still can't get reference to any of the library's methods. https://i.imgur.com/YZze54k.png

Comment: @DIRTYDAVE Can you clarify what are in the 'core','utils','abi' directories - i.e. java files, class files or JARs? As that is a different project, you may want to look into making it a module for your Android app to reference.

Comment: @MorrisonChang yeah, in the github link above, each of those 3 directories contain a gradle/wrapper folder,
src folder,
build.gradle file,
gradlew file,
gradlew.bat,

Comment: For abi: copy the org directory to the java directory of your project. You can then use the package org.tron.trident.abi.spi;